# PHP Namespaces, what does use and \ means, and do they autoload classes?

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm trying to educate myself with PHP 5.3/PHP 5.4 OOP features.

I've tried to code something like this. It doesn't work, though.

index.php

```
namespace Website;

use Website\Database as Database;

class Website extends Database
{
    function __construct()
    {
        echo "Test";
    }
}

$website = new Website();
```

./Website/Database.php

```
namespace Website\Database;

class Database
{
    function construct()
    {
        echo "Hello from Database";
    }
}
```

I know how to make classes, relate them to eachother etc. but whenever I add namespace to the top, everything gets broken.

So I would like to ask a few elementary things;

**Q1**: Does `use ClassName;` means it autoloads/includes the class?

**Q2**: What does `\` means without anything on left side. (e.g new \Database();)

**Q3**: Does `\` means a directory in PHP, or that is only how developers treat it as?

**Q4**: What changes has to be done in my script to get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to your first three questions:

Namespacing !== Autoloading, namespacing is a way of simplifying your class structures, and allows "overloading" of classes in different namespaces; autoloading is automatically loading files when they are needed: they aren't the same thing. If you're using namespaces, you probably also want to use an autoloader as well.

A "leading" `\` is the global scope for namespacing; and subsequent `\` then serve as the namespace separator

`\` is a namespace separator; directory separators are `/` or `\` in filespecs depending on platform; but `/` works on all platforms anyway so should really be used for all cross-platform developments. There is also the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant

Comment: Q1: So if I use use Database; in a file; do I need to require_once('Database.php')? Q2: Clear enough. Q3: Yeah, I know about it, but when I check the sources of some frameworks, they use something like: use ExceptionHandler\FileHandler\FileUploadException; and the real path to the file is like ./ExceptionHandler/FileHandler/FileUploadException.php - Is it something developers treat as directories cause it is easier to find what they're looking for?

Comment: Q1 - you either need to require, or include an autoloader that can handle namespaces classes

Comment: Directory structures mapped to namespace structures is just a convenience.... it's not mandatory, but it's easier to work with - but the two shouldn't be considered identical as this can lead to a misunderstanding of what namespaces actually are

Answer (score 2):

**A1:** If you `use` a class that is not yet loaded, the autoloader will kick in. But you need to write your own autoloader to make sure (namespaced) classes will be loaded.

untested example:

```
function autoloader($className){
    $fileName = str_replace('\\', DIRCTORY_SEPARATOR, $className);
    include __DIR__ . $fileName;
}
spl_autoload_register(autoloader);
```

This assumes the loader is in the application root. And it does not do error checking, and it may need another directory separator added somewhere.

**A2:** A leading `\` means global namespace, to indicate that the class name is not in the current namespace.

**A3:** the namespace does not need to match the directory structure, but most developers will prefer it. It also makes autoloading easier.

Comment: A1: Is there an example how an autoloader like this can we written? I currently use spl_autoload_register() to load classes. A2 and A3: Clear enough!

Comment: You want to look at some of the fig compliant autoloaders; e.g. https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md or (the recommended choice) https://gist.github.com/jwage/221634

Comment: @Arjan; Could you have a look at my approach? https://gist.github.com/Aristy/130eb1ba149af5ce9f82 It is also similar to yours. Will it work with namespaces?